# MySQL/MariaDB unable to handle unique keys with when using utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, mariadb

We have MySQL table with utf8mb4 strings:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`code` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `test_code_unique` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

When inserting special characters there appears to be wrong conversion:

```
mysql> insert into `test` (`code`, `name`) values ('munster', 'Munster');


mysql> insert into `test` (`code`, `name`) values ('münster', 'Münster');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'münster' for key 'test_code_unique'


mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE code='münster';
+----+---------+---------+
| id | name    | code    |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | Munster | munster |
+----+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE code='munster';
+----+---------+---------+
| id | name    | code    |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | Munster | munster |
+----+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If unique key is removed second insert works but a search returns 2 rows even if query is different:

```
mysql> drop table test;


CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`code` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


mysql> insert into `test` (`code`, `name`) values ('munster', 'Munster');


mysql> insert into `test` (`code`, `name`) values ('münster', 'Münster');


mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE code='münster';
+----+----------+----------+
| id | name     | code     |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | Munster  | munster  |
|  2 | Münster  | münster  |
+----+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE code='munster';
+----+----------+----------+
| id | name     | code     |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | Munster  | munster  |
|  2 | Münster  | münster  |
+----+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This has been tested on both MySQL 5.7 and MariaDB 10.2 and they both give same results.

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this seemingly mysterious problem is that you're using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation, and that collation intentionally ignores differences in accented characters vs non-accented characters. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html

To resolve this, change collation on `code` column to `utf8mb4_bin`, which will distinguish between accented characters and non-accented characters, and also between caSe.